# Connecting to RPC for too long? "Invalid JSON RPC response"

Tags: web3js, json-rpc

I have a script that's "always" connected to the Fantom chain (EVM compatible) during the duration of execution.

```
const web3    = new Web3("https://rpc.ftm.tools/", {
    reconnect: {
        auto: true,
        delay: 1000, // ms  
        maxAttempts: 5,
        onTimeout: false
    }
});
```

During the execution of the script (which is usually in scan mode on blockchain / API providers), I would get this error message randomly. I have no idea which part of web3.js is throwing this error, what it means, or how to remedy. Any ideas?

```
Invalid JSON response: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class=\"no-js ie6 oldie\" lang=\"en-US\"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class=\"n
o-js ie7 oldie\" lang=\"en-US\"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class=\"no-js ie8 oldie\" lang=\"en-US\"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if gt IE 
8]><!--> <html class=\"no-js\" lang=\"en-US\"> <!--<![endif]-->\n<head>\n<title>Temporarily unavailable | rpc.ftm.tools | Cloudflare</title><
/title>\n<meta charset=\"UTF-8\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compa
tible\" content=\"IE=Edge,chrome=1\" />\n<meta name=\"robots\" content=\"noindex, nofollow\" />\n<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=devi
ce-width,initial-scale=1\" />\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" id=\"cf_styles-css\" href=\"/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\
"screen,projection\" />\n<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel=\"stylesheet\" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href=\"/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css\" type=\"tex
t/css\" media=\"screen,projection\" /><![endif]-->\n<style type=\"text/css\">body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>\n\n\n<!--[if gte IE 10]><!-->\n
<script>\n  if (!navigator.cookieEnabled) {\n    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {\n      var cookieEl = document.get
ElementById('cookie-alert');\n      cookieEl.style.display = 'block';\n    })\n  }\n</script>\n<!--<![endif]-->\n\n\n</head>\n<body>\n  <div 
id=\"cf-wrapper\">\n    <div class=\"cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error\" id=\"cookie-alert\" data-translate=\"enable_cookies\">Please e
nable cookies.</div>\n    <div id=\"cf-error-details\" class=\"cf-error-details-wrapper\">\n      <div class=\"cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-
overview\">\n        <h1>\n          <span class=\"cf-error-type\" data-translate=\"error\">Error</span>\n          <span class=\"cf-error-co
de\">1105</span>\n          <small class=\"heading-ray-id\">Ray ID: 6f73e023bc8d0cd9 &bull; 2022-04-05 18:46:49 UTC</small>\n        </h1>\n 
       <h2 class=\"cf-subheadline\" data-translate=\"error_desc\">Temporarily unavailable</h2>\n      </div><!-- /.header -->\n\n      <secti
on></section><!-- spacer -->\n\n      <div class=\"cf-section cf-wrapper\">\n        <div class=\"cf-columns two\">\n          <div class=\"c
f-column\">\n            <h2 data-translate=\"what_happened\">What happened?</h2>\n            <p>You've requested a page on a website (rpc.f
tm.tools) that is on the <a data-orig-proto=\"https\" data-orig-ref=\"www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing/\" target=\"_blank\">Cloudflare</a
> network. The page could not be rendered due to a temporary fault.</p>\n          </div>\n\n          \n        </div>\n      </div><!-- /.s
ection -->\n\n      <div class=\"cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-sol
id border-0 border-t border-gray-300\">\n  <p class=\"text-13\">\n    <span class=\"cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1\">Cloudflare Ray ID: <str
ong class=\"font-semibold\">6f73e023bc8d0cd9</strong></span>\n    <span class=\"cf-footer-separator sm:hidden\">&bull;</span>\n    <span clas
s=\"cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1\"><span>Your IP</span>: [DELETED] </span>\n    <span class=\"cf-footer-separator sm:hidden\">&bull;</
span>\n    <span class=\"cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1\"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel=\"noopener noreferrer\" href=\"h
ttps://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing\" id=\"brand_link\" target=\"_blank\">Cloudflare</a></span>\n    \n  </p>\n</div><!-- /.error-foo
ter -->\n\n\n    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->\n  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->\n\n  <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n  window._cf_transl
ation = {};\n  \n  \n</script>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this happens b/c RPC connection to rpc.ftm.tools is flaky. Connect to other fantom RPCs: https://ftm.guru/rpc.html